# Cant connect mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to connect my MySQL database `kuvarskir` with my PHP code. Then inputted this into html:

```
<?php
        include "mysql.php";
        $recepti = execute_sql("SELECT * FROM recepti");
        foreach($recepti as $recept)
        {
        ?>
            <article>
                <h2><?=$recept["naziv"]?></h2>
                <i><?=$recept["sastojci"]?></i>
                <p><?=$recept["uputstvo"]?></p>
            </article>

        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

but its not working.

i think there is error with `mysql.php` file, here's the code:

```
<?php
function init_sql()
{

    global $conn;
    $host = "localhost";
    $db = "kuvarskir";

    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";

    try
    {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;

        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db", $username, $password, $pdo_options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die("Database connection failed!");
    }
}

function execute_sql($sql, $params=[])
{
    global $conn;

    if ($conn == null)
        init_sql();
    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($params);

        $data = array();

        if ($stmt->columnCount() == 0) //INSERT / UPDATE
            return $stmt->rowCount();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            $data[] = $row;

        return $data;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die("somting glitched. error is: $e");
    }
}
?>
```

maybe, there is problem with my localhost, which is `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin`

also here is picture of database

[image: db]

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Is the page returning a 500 or what is its status code?

Comment: your localhost should probably be `localhost:3006` ... phpMyAdmin **is not** a database system, it is just some php sugar candy on top of apache and mysql that provides a visualization capability over the underlying components.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg It is correct in the PHP, `$host = "localhost";` The default port (3306, think you have a typo) should map over. I agree about the `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: @user3783243 ahhh right ... then i suggest that the first try-catch should catch any exception and throwable to see the real nature of the issue.

Comment: nope. its still not working. idk why.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Is it throwing an exception in the `init_sql` or `execute_sql` or is it some other issue?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/QjhGrbU

Comment: its litteraly not saying error

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6BC2dHCE

Comment: this is entire code

Comment: @reed its still making error

Comment: Some troubleshooting you can try, to identify the problem: First lines of your script, [display errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/802469). do `var_dump($recepti)` after calling `execute_sql`. Try right click -> View Page Source (often times my errors won't show until I view page source). Try your query inside phpmyadmin and make sure it works there.

Comment: And maybe change `catch(PDOException $e)` to `catch(Exception $e)`, just in case some other exception is being thrown.

Comment: sadly, its not working. i will try it on anather computer to see if it will work then. Thanks by the way